# What does LC_CTYPE locale translation actually do?

Tags: locale

I've been trying to understand what LC_CTYPE actually does - can anyone tell me if this is true and if so, point me at the documentation that explains this?

It seems that if I have a locale of en_US.utf8 and I try to print an extended (>=128) ASCII character, I get the character I expect except if I do this:

`LC_CTYPE=C <my-command>`

If I do this then I seem to get the 2-byte UTF-8 representation of the character.

So does this mean that:

1. There is some locale that everything translates TO, and if so, what is it?
2. LC_CTYPE is defining what I am translating FROM so if I set LC_CTYPE to UTF-8 already, it assumes I don't need any translation.

Thanks.